# Negative z-index element appears above background of containing element

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a CSS3 animated menu but I'm running into an issue where low-index elements are appearing on top of the containing elements, which ruins the "sliding out" effect.

The HTML is:

```
<html>
  <head><title>CSS3 Experiments</title></head>
  <body class="menu-metal effect-hovermenu">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="name"><span>Effect: Hover Menu</span></div>
            <div class="short"><span>Display menu on hover</span></div>
            <div class="long"><span>A CSS3-transition enabled hover menu based on the design at http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-dropdown-menu/ .</span></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The condensed relevant CSS is

```
.effect-hovermenu #container li {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
.effect-hovermenu #container li .short {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1000;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  color: black;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.effect-hovermenu #container li:hover .short {
  left: 110%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

A working demonstration of the issue is available at http://jsfiddle.net/scottrabin/FxZrz/ . I've tried setting the `position` property on multiple elements, modifying the `z-index` values, `overflow`, and finally realized I was shooting in the dark and not getting any closer to an answer.

In particular, the undesired effect is on hovering over the element; during the transition period, the text is switched to `visibility: visible;`, and it immediately renders on top of the button element. The ideal behavior would have the element render beneath the `ul` so it would appear to slide out from "behind" the menu.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a z-index in an element, you are creating a **stacking context**. Each element within the element is now part of his stacking context and cannot appear beneath it. By default, all elements are part of a **root** stacking context.

[This documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) may help you solve your problem.

Comment: I tried removing the `z-index` and `position` properties of the containing `li` and `ul`, to no avail. I also tried setting `z-index` to `auto`, which (according to spec) causes the box to not establish a new stacking context. I knew about stacking contexts before and tried to fix it, but couldn't get it to render underneath the parent element.